# I am not able to access the `Set` list from the other file even after importing the file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an empty list in which the items are added when the items are selected. But I'm not able to access the list in a different file which is of type `Set` to avoid duplicates. Also the list has two types of items, images and text(inside the `children` of  a `Row`). The list is in another file and except this list everything can be accessed. I don't know why this is happening, can anyone help?

My code:

```
final Set saved = Set(); //This thing is not getting accessed

class FavoriteList extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_FavoriteListState createState() => _FavoriteListState();
}

class _FavoriteListState extends State<FavoriteList> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Add to Favorites!'),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red),
  // backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 53,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CheckboxListTile(
          activeColor: Colors.red,
          checkColor: Colors.white,
          // value: _saved.contains(context), // changed
          value: saved.contains(index),
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              // isChecked = val;           // changed
              // if(val == true){           // changed
              //   _saved.add(context);     // changed
              // } else{                    // changed
              //   _saved.remove(context);  // changed
              // }                          // changed
              if (val == true) {
                saved.add(index);
              } else {
                saved.remove(index);
              }
            });
          },
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Text(nameOfSite[index]),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    foregroundColor: Colors.red,
    child: Icon(Icons.check),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.pop<Set>(context, saved);
    },
  ),
);
  }
  }
```

The part where I want it to be accessed:

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    // Text(
    //   'Add Your Favorite Sites Here!❤',
    //   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    // ),
    // Container(
    //   child: Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 150, color: Colors.blue[100]),
    // ),
    SizedBox(height: 250),
    FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => FavoriteList(),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ],
);
  }
  }
```

Comment: post code snippets... It's difficult to get to the core of the problem with just description.

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi i've updated the question. you can have a look now

Comment: I am not seeing a problem here, Set `saved` is accessible on the second page. Even new values are there as well. Tell me, When do you want to access it or how is it not accessible?

Comment: sorry, which new values? are you talking about the ones which "should be saved" on clicking the back button or the ones which are displayed on List Screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a problem of access to the `Set` from the `FavoriteList` widget.

You have already created a way to get the latest value of `saved` Set from the `FavoriteList`, which is below:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
foregroundColor: Colors.red,
child: Icon(Icons.check),
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pop<Set>(context, saved);
  },
)
```

So, this way you will get the latest value of `saved` when the `FavoriteList` Widget 
is poped out.

You can use the following approach to catch the new value, make change in `SecondPage`'s code,
From :

```
FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
       Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return FavoriteList();
            },
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
    ),
```

To:

```
 FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    Set newSet = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return FavoriteList();
        },
      ),
    );

    print('newSet: $newSet');
  },
  child: Icon(Icons.add),
  foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
),
```

The `newSet` value is the latest values that are result of the `FavoriteList` Widget.
It can be Used to update the UI in `SecondPage`. Just create a list in SecondPage`State`List favorites = List();`. Use this list to populate your UI however you like.

Now, when you catch the `saved` Set in `FloatingActionButton` just do Following:

```
setState((){
  favoriteList = newSet.toList();
});
```

**Note:**
However, I would like to suggest that if you are providing access to something from multiple widgets, make sure to keep the accessed value in the widget on top of all widgets.

If you need more help, let me know in the comments.

Comment: yeah one more thing, what do I return in the `build` method

Comment: no changes are required, if you see closely, only `onPressed` is modified. `FloatingActionButton` will be returned as widget as usual.

Comment: yeah but how do I return the list of the 'favorites' i mean now i know that the items are saving as i checked in the console but i am not able to do that on the screen. i want your help with that! thank you

Comment: I have updated the answer. After getting new values in `SecondPage` it's up to you, how to show them.

Comment: Sir the technical work is done but I'm just not able to make the layout of the list. the image.asset() is not taking the `index` value for `saved` and so is the case with the Text() widget. if you can please check my code?my entire code is [here](https://github.com/theyashjha/aioapp). The problem is just in two files. thank you

Comment: For images instead of: 
`Image.asset('lib/images/${saved[index]}');`

try this: 

`int siteIndex= saved[index];`

`Image.asset('lib/images/${images[siteIndex]}');`


Same for the Text, use `nameOfSite` list with site index.